# PHP Echo causes file to add html end comment dashes

Tags: php, html, mysql

When I'm trying to connect to a database in order to search for a username and password, it seems that running 'echo' command for any option kills the entire page and doesn't execute the rest of the code.

Here is my PHP file:

```
 <html>
 <body>

 <?php
    //setting variables for connecting to database
    error_reporting(0);
    $host     = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $db       = 'aquamandb';
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

    //connecting to the database
    $connect  = new mysqli($host,$username, $password, $db) or die("Unable to connect");

    //getting the username, user type, and password for sanitizing
    $_US_username = $_GET['username'];
    $_US_password = $_GET['password'];

    //sanitize the variable to remove SQL statements that could drop the database potentially.
    $username     = mysql_real_escape_string($_US_username);
    $password     = mysql_real_escape_string($_US_password);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $result   = mysql_query($sql);  

    //Send alert to page if there is not a match found between username password and user type
    if(!$result)
    {
        die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    else
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        if($row['type'] == 1)
        {
            echo '<form name   = "auto" action = "../admin-dash.html" method = "POST">';
        }
        else if($row['type'] == 2)
        {
            echo '<form name   = "auto" action = "../sigadmin-dash.html" method = "POST">';
        } else
        {
            echo '<form name   = "auto" action = "../sigusr-dash.html" method = "POST">';
        }
    }
   ?>
```

Note: I'm only posting a link to the PHP code because the file would never format correctly and would actually cause the same issue when I tried to use it on my website.

The issue is at Line 37.  The echo statement stops, it doesn't create the form, and it just prints the rest of the elseif statements in regular text on the live web page.

If there are any clues as to what I am doing wrong (if I'm formatting something wrong) would be fantastic.

Comment: I do know not to use GET for usernames and passwords i changed it in an attempt to debug the problems.

Comment: It is a requirement to have a minimal verifyable example. Links to other places with the code can be taken down, leaving to a question without code. This is known as "link rotting". This way, your question will be useless. Please, move the code into the question and explain where the error is **in the code**.

Comment: IDE can easily tell where you forgot a semi -colon.

Comment: @frz3993 incorrect, this did not solve the issue or change it in anyway what happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you don't just put the form inside the  html and call $_POST or $GET Inside php it would be way more simple that way. The error I see is right before line 37 where you forgot your(";") but even fixed it doesn't print the form i dont even think its processing your if but not sure. Also  you should use  prepared statements instead of mysql_real_escape_string , also your using mysqli to initially connect then you use mysql while escaping. .Try something like this:::::

```
      <!doctype html>
      <html>
      <body>
      <form action = "whatever.php method = "post">
      <input type = "email" name = "email" />
      <input type = "password" name = "password" />
      <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "insert" />
      </form>

    <?php
     // connect to the server
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'usename', 'password', 'database');
    // check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
    } else {
 echo "your connection was successful";

   }
if($_POST && isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['name'] )) {
    $email = ( $_POST["email"]);
    $pass = ($_POST["password"]);


     $query = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT pass FROM database
     WHERE  email = ? ");

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query,'s', $email );

    mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query, $email);



  if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($query)) {

  echo "<br />";
    echo "SUCCESS at query";

    if (password_verify($input, $id)) {
    echo "matching pass" . header("Location: inserh.php");
    } else{
    echo "not a  match";

        }


      }
    mysqli_stmt_close($query);
    }


    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Hope this helps Also this script verifies the hashed password using bcrypt!

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing semi colon @ the end of line 34:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: This is not the issue and didn't fix the error that was happening.

Comment: What PH version are you running?

Comment: PHP version: 7.0.4

Comment: So you need to use mysqli_query instead of mysql_query and mysqli_fetch_array. The old mysql extension isn't supported anymore in PHP 7

Comment: Indeed, but im still running into the same issue, the "--" Is being added at the end of that echo statement on line 37

Answer (score 0):

`$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)` is missing a `;` and is crashing your script

Comment: Still did not fix the issue.

Comment: It is printing the form, however, you must add the form elements inside (such as a submit and input buttons) and close the form, otherwise there is nothing to show

Comment: Thank you RMD, i forgot i had removed an  onload="document.auto.submit()" so it would auto submit the form. Still having an issue with it redirecting to the correct page though, is the if-statement formatted correctly? To find the column named type, that matches what the query returned?

Comment: [userID][username][type][password] is the layout of the columns, and im trying to see if the type matches a certain one to redicrect to the correct page